# Struggling with asynchronous JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to get this function to asynchronously call an API and return the response's JSON. However, the function returns nothing, before the API call has returned and populated `res`.

I'm confused about the proper usage of asynchronous JavaScript in this use case.

From my understanding, once `async` has been declared in a function, then the code will pause whenever it hits an `await` until the `await` has returned a promise. But that obviously isn't the case. What am I missing?

```
        let queryApi = async (query) => {
            const url = "http://localhost:3000/test";
            const response = await fetch(url)

            const res = await response.json();
            return res;
        }
```

Thanks friends!

Comment: Try to declare your `res` variable outside the async function.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan, no that would be unnecessary.

Comment: Are you awaiting at the call site? I.e. `const result = await queryApi(query)` versus `const result = queryApi(query)`

Comment: I'm fairly sure the problem is stemming from an improper use of `fetch()`. Fetch returns a promise, which you can't just call `.json()` on.

Comment: @David Oh really? The code works synchronously.

Comment: Promise.json() isn't defined. Usually it's `fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))`.

Comment: @David you can... when `fetch` returns the `Promise` you’re meant to use the `.then` callback or `async/await` to access the response from the URL, then you use a body method (`.json()`) to return the response for it to be manipulated. So his code is perfectly okay.

Comment: Gotcha fair enough. I'm not too familiar with that.

Comment: Oh man. The problem appears to be me trying to loop through a couple of these ```queryApi``` functions with a ```.forEach``` when I should be using ```.map```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is how Promises work. You must call asynchronous code from an asynchronous setting or a top-level module. So let's say you have the following code (adjusted).

```js
let queryApi = async (query) => {
    const response = await fetch(query);
    const res = await response.json();
    return res;
}
```

You can call it like so:

```js
let result = await queryApi('https://www.example.com');
console.log(result);
```

It must be inside an asynchronous function OR in a `<script type='module'></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some problems with your braces.
Actually you need something like this:

```
        const queryApi = async (query) => {
            const response = await fetch(query);
            const res = await response.json();
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: Yeah I thought that too but then thought typos?